# Unable to connect to Sql server 2016 express

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2016-express

I have two sql server installed in my machine. The 2016 one shows SQL Server(MSSQLSERVER) name and 2014 one SQLEXPRESS respectively.

When I log in from sql server management studio using this `hostname\SQLEXPRESS` I get loggged into 2014 instance

but when I try to access 2016 version using this `hostname\MSSQLSERVER` It gives me below error:

> a network-related or instance-specific error 26.The server was not
>   found or was not accessible.

In sevice.msc i can see both SQLEXPRESS and MSSQLSERVER up and running.

Comment: Is The Browser server for sql running properly And Also check the Name Pipe is Enable or Not

Comment: MSSQLSERVER being the default instance, you can simply access it with <hostname>

Comment: @dean is correct. Just connect to `hostname`

Answer (score -1):

Run SQL Server Configuration Manager
Expand SQL Server Network Configuration
You should see Protocols for MSSQLServer and Protocols for SQLEXPRESS
Check that the protocols you wish to use are enabled for each instance
If using TCP/IP - Select TCP/IP in the right pane
Right Click and select Properties
Select the IP Addresses tab
Scroll Down to IPAll and change the dynamic ports to 0 (Zero)
You need to do this for both instances
Restart the SQL Server Services